# RPM command stuck/FREEZE when installing RPM file

Tags: filesystems, rhel, rpm

I want to install the following rpm, but for some reason RPM is stuck or frozen and will not install the RPM package. I can't stop it by control-C.

Please advise what could be the problem?

```
 root]# rpm -Uvh --repackage /var/tmp/bash-2.05b-41.8.i386.rpm
```

..... no output here

OR

```
 root]# rpm -Uvh  /var/tmp/bash-2.05b-41.8.i386.rpm
```

RPM verification  ( the last lines )

```
  rpm -Uvvh /var/tmp/bash-2.05b-41.8.i386.rpm
  .
  .
  .

  D: installing binary packages
  D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Pubkeys
  D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname
  D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename
  D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename
  D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
  D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm/Packages
  D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm/Packages joinenv
  D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages create mode=0x42
  D: mounted filesystems:
  D:     i    dev bsize       bavail       iavail mount point
```

Comment: Which distribution and version?

Comment: on Linux red-hat 3 , its not work on any RPM ,

Comment: From where do you got this RPM für RHEL3?

Comment: Are other commands (like 'ls') working fine?

Comment: I am shell shocked!

Answer (score 5):

`rpm` may be waiting for a lock to be freed.

First, run `ps -ef | grep rpm` to see if you have any RPM commands running.  If you do, kill them using `kill -9`.

Next, delete any leftover locks `rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db.0*`

Then try your rpm command again. If it still doesn't work, repeat as above, but then also run `rpm --rebuilddb` before trying your install again.

Edit:

If this hasn't solved the problem, you may have a non-responsive filesystem.
Does `df` also hang? If it does, that's probably your problem. `cat /etc/mtab` and find out what filesystem is mounted on the next line after the last output from `df` then try to unmount that filesystem.

Comment: I do all you write , and still isnt work - RPM is hang/freeze/stuck

Comment: Is there any output if you run `rpm -Uvvh /var/tmp/bash-2.05b-41.8.i386.rpm`? The extra v should cause it to be more verbose. If there's any output, please paste it into your question.

Comment: please look on the update quastion

Comment: I added a suggestion as an edit in my answer. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a stale lock.

A reboot would remove a stale lock (and a stale futex), so
would "rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*" or "cd /var/lib/rpm && db_recover -ev".

If still hanging, use -Uvv instead of -Uvh to find out
operation rpm is trying to perform.

---

From the -Uvv output, rpm is finding the size of mounted file systems.

You likely have an NFS mount to a server that isn't responding

Comment: I had an unusable NFS mount. Thanks for your tip.